# Instantiate variables to None in Python

Tags: python

Why do these two blocks of code not do the same thing?

```
category = None
prodid_brand = None
prod_type = None
prod_application = None
prod_handletype = None
prod_series = None
```

I wanted to "clean up" my code by doing the following, but it does not work the same as the code above.

```
column_list = [category, prodid_brand, prod_type, prod_application, 
               prod_handletype, prod_series]

for col in column_list:
    col = None
```

Also is there a "cleaner" way to instantiate all the variables than the top block of code.

Comment: "but it does not work the same as the code above." *How?*

Comment: I doubt it works at all, you've got a list full of `NameError`s. You should read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html; it's not clear why you thought they *would* do the same thing.

Comment: `category = prodid_brand = prod_type = prod_application = prod_handletype = prod_series = None`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other answers are great ways to more cleanly/efficiently set all the variables to None.

However, to answer this question:

> Why do these two blocks of code not do the same thing?

The reason is, with your first line

```
column_list = [category, prodid_brand, prod_type, prod_application, 
               prod_handletype, prod_series]
```

you're actually setting the variable at each index in the list equal to each of those variables. So, `column_list[0] = category`, `column_list[1] = prodid_brand`, etc.

Then with the next lines

```
for col in column_list:
    col = None
```

you just changing the variable at each of those list indexes, and setting them to None (equivalent to `column_list[0] = None`).

Hence why none of your initial variables (`category`, `prodid_brand`, etc) are getting set, and you're ending up with a list of six `None` values instead.

Comment: You're not changing the list indexes. The list is not changed. You're merely changing the variable `col`, which has no knowledge of any list elements.

Comment: @kindall good point. I updated my answer to be more accurate.

Answer (score 6):

You can chain the assignments like:

```
category = prodid_brand = prod_type = None
prod_application = prod_handletype = prod_series = None
```

Answer (score 2):

You can assign multiple variables to the same object

```
var1 = var2 = None
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question "Why do these two blocks of code not do the same thing?"

Your first block of code is assigning None to variables - aka initializing them

Your second block of code is generating a variable as it iterates through the list `column_list` - assigning a value to the variable `col` in your for loop does actually make `col` evaluate to `None` but only in that loop (aka it isn't assigning it back to the original list)

If you want to assign variables in the loop -

```
column_list = [category, prodid_brand, prod_type, prod_application, 
           prod_handletype, prod_series]

for index,value in enumerate(column_list):
    column_list[index] = None
```

but this will infact give you a list of None's

`column_list = [None,None,None,None,None,None]`
not
`column_list = [category=None, prodid_brand=None, prod_type=None, prod_application=None, prod_handletype=None, prod_series=None]`

Looks like maybe you would be better served by a dictionary than a list.

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
a, b, c, d = (None,) * 4
f, g, h, i = (False,) * 4
print(a, b, c, d, f, g, h, i)
```

output:

```
None None None None False False False False
```